# Anagrams: From Food to Food

Tags: anagram

A challenge a friend and I came up with to entertain ourselves, but found a little too taxing:

*Find 5 single word foods (i.e. comestibles or dishes) whose letters can be reshuffled to give another single word food.*

We managed to find two:

> LEMON <--> MELON
> PASTA <--> TAPAS

It seems somewhat nontrivial to find any more! Another that was thought of was MASH <--> HAMS, but we didn't really count it due to the unnatural pluralisation of ham (whereas tapas is naturally a plural in the English vernacular). One more example of a disallowed solution is SCONE <--> CONES, due to the vagueness of cones (and again, a pluralisation - but chiefly the former).

Any ideas? Thanks

*Edit: A few people are including beverages - my intention was to exclude these from the 'food' world.*

Comment: You should consider a no computer Tag. There are Anagram Solvers on the Net which only require putting any word in and instantly gives the anagrams

Comment: I suppose if there was a ready database of all edibles/dishes, a quick script could be written.

Comment: @DEEM I agree, that would be cheating.

Comment: @DEEM Personally I think it would be very interesting to see a full list of solutions that a computer script can generate.

Comment: Hams! Terrific!

Comment: Oh, no, I meant steamed MASH, that's what I call mashed potatos. It's a regional dialect.

Comment: Would pineapple and applepine count? ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here are three pretty decent ones to take you up to five:

> SKATE (a kind of fish) and STEAK.
>  COLLOPS (= slices of meat, usually found in plural) and SCOLLOP (a less common but acceptable spelling of SCALLOP).
>  RAPE (the root of the turnip; also another related plant from which cooking oil is made) and PEAR.

These are pushing it a bit:

> CHILI (hot pepper or a dish made therefrom, though CHILLI is a better spelling) and LICHI (an unusual spelling of LYCHEE or LITCHI, an aromatic Chinese fruit).
>  MARG (short for MARGARINE) and GRAM (as in gram flour, used for making papadums and the like).

And I think these are clearly impermissible:

> EDAM (a Dutch cheese) and MEAD (an alcoholic drink rather than a food).
>  GRAIN (wheat, barley, oats, etc.) and GARNI (as in BOUQUET GARNI, but I don't think anyone uses that abbreviation).
>  DOSA (a kind of Indian bread) and SODA (a drink, or a kind of bread -- but that's definitely called SODA BREAD, not just SODA).

Comment: Dosa and Soda is a valid pair.
Being an India, I testify :)

Comment: Love it, scollop especially. Also I'd count dosa seeing as soda can also mean sodium bicarbonate, a commonplace baking ingredient!

Comment: I'm inclined to rule SODA as valid because 'a soda' is 'a softdrink' in some English-speaking countries and similarly MEAD as Google's dictionary example for the adjective comestible is 'coffee, tea'...  but indeed it is 'comestible' (comer= to eat) not 'beverage' or 'potable'.

Comment: The puzzle specifically asked for *food* rather than *drink* which is why I think SODA is impermissible.

Comment: "What did you have for dinner?" "Just some skate and rape..."

Comment: Hey, don't blame *me* for the fact that some words have two very different meanings.

Comment: @EdmundReed i laughed way too hard.

Answer (score 21):

This is a surprisingly hard task. I managed to find just three so far.

1.

> Sloe (wild plum) --> Sole (fish)

2.

> [Samp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samp) (South African corn dish) --> Spam (processed meat)

3.

> Gota (Indian dish) --> Goat (you know, the maa-ing type :D )

Comment: Impressive solutions!

Comment: New pair added.

Answer (score 12):

I think this may count:

> CASSEROLE  ( a large, deep dish used both in the oven and as a serving vessel. The word is also used for the food cooked and served in such a vessel)
>  ESCAROLES (escarole is also called broad-leaved endive)

Comment: Hmm...it depends. The OP excluded `Mash <--> Hams` because of the pluralisation, and the same thing is happening here. Congratulations on making such a long one, though!

Comment: @Jǝssǝ ah snap, I was so excited about thinking of that one I forgot about the pluralisation. And thinking about it, I wouldn't have a plate of escaroles, I'd have a plate of escarole. I'll delete if necessary (my first answer here, so if that's the accepted etiquette I'll remove it).

Comment: Terribly sorry to disappoint you, I know the feeling. I think you can leave your answer here, though. You certainly made a stab at it!

Comment: Ah sorry to be a stickler! The 's' appendage is almost entirely dwarfed by its impressive length though, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if this is serious or not, or lateral thinking, but

> in the context of the book 'Alive: The Story of the Andes Survivors' rugby TEAM becomes MEAT for the team.

Comment: Hmm. If we aren't ruling out cannibalism, tutor/trout and rosti/tiros would be on the list as well as others.

Answer (score 10):

Here is one:

> Polish cake [babka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babka_(cake)) turns into [kabab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabab) (another way of saying kebab).

Comment: From the Middle East to the Eastern bloc, nice!

Answer (score 10):

One more to add (it's a tricky challenge!):

> RAGU (from italian cusine, a meat-based sauce) > GUAR (legume used to produce guar gum/ guar beans and leaves used in cooking)

And this one tenuous at best:

> LIVER > ERVIL (ancient grain legume, variety of Vetch plant which is member of the of pea family - edible but not commonly used in modern cooking from what I can see. )

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! you should [take the tour](/tour) for an easy badge.

Comment: Oh my guar, yes

Answer (score 9):

A bit late, but here is one more:

> LAMB and BALM (a herb, also known as lemon balm)

Answer (score 5):

I could only think of one:

> Smelt ([The Fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smelt_(fish)#As_food)) -> Melts ([The Sandwiches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melt_sandwich))

Comment: Nice! Gotta disallow it on the basis of the pluralisation constraint here though (see OP).

Answer (score 3):

How about a food to a food to a food?:

> SWINE <-> SINEW (part of meat) <-> WINES

Comment: Swine: bit sketchy? Wines: pluralised (see OP) + wine's a beverage (didn't intend for beverages to be counted as 'foods').

Comment: @SValera swine is not a bit sketchy in places like North America.

Answer (score 2):

I could only think of one honest one:

> TREACLE(a type of syrup like molasses)/CLARETE (a type of rose wine)

And one wasn't quite there, but it was close so I still wanted to include it:

> SUNCHOKE(also called a Jerusalem artichoke)/HONEySUCKle (a delicious edible plant that tastes like honey, but I'm missing the y, l, and e)

Comment: Unfortunately it is spelled CLARET, without a second E.

Comment: Hi Jaap, the Spanish variety of rose Rioja is in fact spelled Clarete!  https://www.thecultureist.com/2013/07/11/clarete-la-rioja-spanish-wine/

Comment: Nice anagram! I hadn't intended for beverages to be included in the 'food' world though

Answer (score 2):

This one's too terrible to leave out

> DOG (What? Some people eat dog) -> GOD (Communion)

Comment: Humour points awarded

Answer (score 0):

If drinks were allowed I'd add:

Pea-tomato (tomatoes grown tiny like peas) <-> Potato-tea (a drink sadly)

I like the challenge

Comment: Unfortunately, *even if* drinks were included, there remain two objections: (1) Hyphenating two-word items is not a legitimate tactic to render them one word items as required, (2) There is clearly an extra 't' used in the the tea reshuffle, in place of what should be an 'm'. This obviously isn't an anagram... Sorry! Good luck.

Comment: Oh boy, I knew writing on the train would bite me in the butt, I even read the post twice. Thanks for the clear and concise criticism, you're absolutely on point. I'll try and think of something within the restrictions laid out by your post.

Comment: Looking forward to seeing what you come up with : -)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some types of cheese that can transform into types of food, which I found while answering [a similar challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75421/anagrams-from-cheese-to-sneeze):

> **Legato -> Gelato** [Italian ice cream]
>
>  **Ragstone -> Estragon** [Another name for tarragon]
>
>  **Esrom -> S'more** [If you can even call it 'food' ;)]

And this one doesn't quite follow the rules, but I have to mention...

> **Friesago** cheese, which perfectly transforms into **Foie-gras**.