# Anagrams: From Cheese to Sneeze

Tags: no-computers, anagram

## Anagram time!

**Similar to [Anagrams: From Food to Food](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68524/anagrams-from-food-to-food), but this time its *From Cheese to Sneeze, or (almost) Anything You Please***.

### Brief:

> **You must turn the names of cheeses into *common nouns* using anagrams**

### The rules:

- You may not use a computer *to do the anagrams* (researching the names of cheeses online is fine).
- You must use single-word names to make single-word answers; hyphenated words are not allowed.
- Common spelling must be used (your local spelling is fine), using alternate spelling to make a word work is not allowed.
- Slang and abbreviations are not allowed.

### Allowances:

- Pluralisation is fine

### Examples:

> `Edam <———> Dame` goes; `Edam <———> Made` does not because 'made' is not a common noun.
>
> `Brie <———> Bier` works

## Have fun!

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, why are answers hidden for this question? If no-one peeks you'll just get many of the same answers repeatedly. If I wanted to find a novel one, I'd have to peek at them all.

Comment: just a remark: there really is no way to check if someone used a computer or not

Comment: Are the anagrams allowed to be more than one word if the cheese is just the one word?

Comment: @Ivo: I'll leave that to their conscience.

Comment: @Frazzle: In short, no. I'll edit to make that absolutely clear.

Comment: @Jǝssǝ - I didnt think so I just had a good one for Emmental

Answer (score 5):

`goat <———> toga`

I borrowed your arrow.

`blue <———> lube` I don't know if that counts as an abbreviation.
`feta <———> fate/feat`
`parmesan <———> spearman`

My domain knowledge is pretty limited. It basically consists of [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese_Shop_sketch).

Comment: Great work! I thought hard about lube before; it is an abbreviation of lubricant, however many dictionaries seem to almost treat it as a word. Personally I feel that it does not count, but if anyone feels different I'll be happy to let it slide. As for cheese names, [www.cheese.com](https://www.cheese.com) has a great list.

Answer (score 5):

The three easier ones I could think of are:

> Comte -> Comet
>  Munster -> Sternum
>  Feta -> Feat\Fate *[Which I see WAF found first]*

And after going over an extensive cheese list as suggested, I spotted these too:

> Geitost -> Egotist
>  Greve -> Verge
>  Kasseri -> Kaisers
>  Madrona -> Roadman
>  Mascare\Mascares -> Cameras\Massacre
>  Minuet -> Minute
>  Molbo -> Bloom
>  Mona -> Moan
>  Moonglo -> Monolog
>  Ragstone -> Negators
>  Ricotta -> Citator
>  Romano -> Maroon
>  Serat -> Tears [and lots more]
>  Toma -> Atom
>  Ubriaco -> Caribou

...And I posted [some more of these in the food into food challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/75429/10216).

Comment: IIRC, Maroon is an adjective.

Comment: @Hosch250 Well, color names *can* also function as nouns, depending on the context. But even if they can't, the word also means an escaped slave or a castaway.

Comment: Ah, right; I missed that connotation. You got my upvote, anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

Parmesan:

> spearman

Are hyphens allowed? Camembert:

> cat-member (either a cat's body part, or maybe a feline individual who's part of an organization)

Comment: We have once again converged. I made my most recent edit without seeing yours.

Comment: @WAF Lol, nice. What are the odds!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt

1. > `passendale <———> esplanades`
2. > `sirene <———> serine`
3. > `esrom <———> morse`
4. > `orda <———> road`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently timelotem (an anagram of mimolette) is an antipsychotic drug.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a proper noun, not a common noun?